# JavaFX ImageView не работает внешний URL

Tags: java, javafx, imageview

```
<Pane id="profile" layoutX="75.0" layoutY="165.0" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="48.0">
  <ImageView id="avatar" fitHeight="48.0" fitWidth="48.0" layoutX="0.0" layoutY="0.0" smooth="false">
    <Image url="http://path.to/dir/with/pic.png" />
  </ImageView>
</Pane>
```

Набросал такую разметку - ImageView просто не загружается. Пробовал подойти с другой стороны и добавлял `Pane#avatar` с такой логикой

```
ProfilePaneAvatar.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent; -fx-background-image: url('http://path.to/dir/with/pic.png')");
```

Получал такую ошибку:

```
Aug 17, 2023 3:36:39 PM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager getCachedImage
WARNING: Error loading image: http://path.to/dir/with/pic.png
```

Сама цель, если нужно - отобразить аватарку с сервера (любого сайта и т.п.)

Comment: Напрямую с url никак не сделать, JavaFX не позволит ввиду ограничений. Можно только загрузить изображение в ресурсы и затем использовать. Грузить можно при каждом обновлении, например, чтобы подтягивалось актуальное изображение.

Comment: В интернете я в основном увидел только гайды new ImageView( new Image( "URL-TO-IMAGE" ) );
Не могли бы вы привести в пример актуальный гайд?
Попробовал так же через SwingFXUtils.toFXImage( ImageIO.read( new Url("URL-TO-IMAGE").openStream() ) )
Вроде никаких ошибок не дало, однако так же никакого результата

Answer (score 2):

Итак, спустя небольшое кол-во времени я нашел ответ. Как и было отмечено в комментариях - JavaFX не даёт что-либо загрузить извне путём `ImageView( Image(URL) )` или `-fx-background-image: url('URL_STRING')`. Поэтому логика немного иначе. Для начала мы получаем `BufferedImage` с помощью `ImageIO.read()` и потом конвертируем в `javafx.scene.image.Image` с помощью `javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(buffered_image, null)`

Итоговый код для ленивцев:

```
URL url = new URL(STRING_URL);
// устанавливаем соеденение
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
// параметры соеденения
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
// получаем BufferedImage
BufferedImage raw_image = ImageIO.read(connection.getInputStream());

// Конвертируем BufferedImage в знакомый и нужный нам для ImageView Image
Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(raw_image, null);

// Ну и дальше делаем с этим всё, что нам вздумается
someScene.lookup('#someImageViewFXid').setImage(image);
```